# Xcode, How to Preview Images in shared storyboard sourced from different targets

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I have an Xcode 8.2 project with two targets 1) Monkey  2) Donkey

1) Monkey has an asset catalog called MonkeyAssets.xcassets
2) Donkey has an asset catalog called DonkeyAssets.xcassets

The each have an image called LaunchImage

Both Targets share the Storyboard LaunchScreen.storyboard here we display the LaunchImage in an imageview.

How can I switch between monkey/donkey in interface builder? Without running the app.

Interface builder seems to choose one of the asset catalogs and stick with it. I have tried toggling the Target Memberships but this is ignored

Possibly a duplicate but cannot find this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? :/

Comment: no solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. It looks like IB tries to find the closest `.xcassets` folder in the folder's tree. If it finds several in the same folder - it takes the first in alphabetical order or smth like that (due to [post](http://matt.coneybeare.me/using-xcode-asset-catalogs-with-multiple-targets/))

My solution: just separate yours `.xcassets` folders to separate folders (like Donkey and Monkey) and add 2 **Launch.storyboard**s into these folders and mark `Target Membership` for each correspondingly (one `Launch.storyboard` for `Monkey` target and one `Launch.storyboard` for `Donkey` target)

So in the end you must have something similar to:

[files and folders structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rKJf.png)

Works on my XCode 11.0 (11A420a)

Hope this helps

Comment: Making two storyboards defeats the purpose really you now have to maintain twice as much code.